# Entity Framework (EF) and .Net 6 Blazor not updating database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor, blazor-server-side

I need help trying to understand why my Blazor (server-side) component in .net Core 6 is not updating my database when removing an entity, please take a look at my code sample: (beforehand, thanks for all your help!)

First, I'm injecting my db context as follow:

```
@inject AppDbContext db
```

then, below on my code, I decided to query for some data, in this case, Customers as follow:

```
 @code {

   private List<Customer> clients { get; set; }

 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
     clients = await db.Customers.ToListAsync();
 }
```

}

Now, I created a button with a method to delete the customer; first I search the entity, if found, then I remove the item from the "clients" list from the database, as follow:

```
private async Task DeleteCustomer(int CustomerId)
 {    
     Customer? customer = clients.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == CustomerId);

     if (customer is not null)
     {           
         clients.Remove(customer);
         await db.SaveChangesAsync();
     }

 }
```

THE PROBLEM is that the entity is removed from the list but not removed from the database, so when I refresh the item still there, I have to apply another command inside the if to make it work:

```
db.Remove(customer);
```

in other words, I have to remove it from the clients list and in the list also, making the work double, it seems to me it loses completely the connection (or ref) between the list coming from the DB and the database. This is the first time I see something like this, am I missing something? am I using the EF the way I am supposed to do? I can just add that command and make it work but I don't think is a good practice, please help!

Comment: This is the expected functionality. The clients variable is only the result of the customers ToListAsync, so off course you can remove items etc from the list but not the database itself because the client variable does not represent the database context

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that is because this is just how EF works.

The client list is contains the queried elements. Even after remove, it still is a queried element. There is no logical way for Ef to update clients - ESPECIALLY as Clients is a List which has no API for this in a sensible way.

So, you must remove it from both, which is logical.

Actually you get it totally wrong. Removing something from clients is not triggering anything from Ef because it makes no sense to start. I could remove them to THEN run code over it - and would trigger an automatic removal from the db just for filtering something out in the UI. Only the db.Remove actually tells Ef it is to remove it FROM THE DATABASE. This is not double, it is Ef not magically reading your mind.

Comment: I think there's a reference between the list querying data and EF, I never had this problem before on MVC, because the question is.. what happen to the reference to the DbContext?... can you post an example? how can this be achieved automatically? if I ask the DB Context to put the data again in the list, that could be overspending resources... for each change query data again to a list...

In other words... are the list entities not being tracked? I did not clone these objects to be completely independent, their reference was posted to a list, that's all...

Comment: Nope, There is not. ToListAsync creates a list that is not updated or pushing updates down. One ToListAsync is done (and I suggest you look at the code of that - it is in the reverence sources), there is no connection. It is a simple standard List<T>. Because among other things there are a LOT of great used cases where this is not wanted. Simple like that. THere are plenty of examples in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, @TomTom, as you may know, I'm newbie.  It was a surprise because in previous projects using MVC I had no problem with this.  I tried to find documentation on what you mentioned (which is what I think also) but I could not find anything, except that it returns a list, no mentions of references.

Now, what I did is implement what https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaQsmkh1BkQ&t=677s says using DbContextFactory so whenever I need a context I create it, but in my mind is... why should I re-query the data into a list again and again every time something changes? should be a better way?

Comment: MVC - as in asp.net - has a very different life cycle, which likely means that the page was fully refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove  item from dbcontext, not from  the list. After you created view, all your dbcontext was disposed and list is not connected. When you try to delete you have a different db context already.
So you need this

```
public async Task DeleteCustomer(int CustomerId)
 {    
     var customer = await db.Customers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Id == CustomerId);

     if (customer!=null)
     {           
        db.Customers.Remove(customer);
       var result=  await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        // you can add if it makes a difference
      if(result==1)  clients.Remove(customer);

     }

 }
```

after deleting you can call

```
 clients = await db.Customers.ToListAsync();
```

again and get an updated list of customers.

Comment: ok but how to update the list automatically then? query again?

Comment: @GuillermoPerez  What it has to do with Delete? Do you think if you remove  item from clients, your screen will be updated? It is wrong. You have to reload the page.

Comment: No, no, no... it's not what I mean... there's no refresh here, remember this is Blazor... what I'm trying to say is that I did query elements from EF that should be tracked, instead I get a list with the elements but not being tracked at all... when I remove an item from the list, the item disappears from the list but not from the database...

Comment: @GuillermoPerez No you don't neeed anything extra, no any factories that will be recommended to you. After deleteting you just call clients = await db.Customers.ToListAsync(); and you will have an updated list without a customer that was deleted. You should not worry about any tracking. You will have tracking problems if you try to use unit of works and all kind of factories. Everything should be kept very simple. EF has already all staff, and when somebody tries to add some more, problems are startring.

Comment: @GuillermoPerez   you can add if it makes a difference      if(result==1)  clients.Remove(customer); - see my updated answer

Comment: we can create DbContexts as needed as a guy recommended https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaQsmkh1BkQ&t=677s, BUT lets say I have 500 records (as example) with nested data (my daughter has a dog grooming place, so the first list is Customers with pets, pets are entities, and each has notes, etc), getting all that data everytime something changes makes my hair go up... I can't belive this is the way they intended blazor to behave.. is there a better way? in other words, I can't conceive that I have to query the db again to get a refreshed list, what if we have 5k records?

Comment: @GuillermoPerez 5k records is nothing for a computer,  if you just select some simple data. 100k maybe can make a small delay.

Comment: @GuillermoPerez The worst is traking  and race conditions if you start to use  dbcontext factories.